# How to stop Main Menu from extending when it cursor is hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with this Navbar and somehow the 'About and Portfolio' Menu keeps extending sidewards whenever you hover on top of it.
I would like to prevent it from extending.
You can check the code from JSFiddle. Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/JustCraze/gdc56899/1/#

HTML

```
 <ul id="main-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About ￬</a>
                        <ul class="hidden">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Who We Are</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">What We Do</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
                        <ul class="hidden">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Photography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Illustration</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

CSS

```
#wrap-nav {
  display: block;
  margin:2rem;
  z-index: 900;
  padding: 5rem;
}
#main-nav {
  display: block;
  z-index: 950;
  padding: 1rem;
  float: right;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:.1rem;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
    display:block;
    min-width:140px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    background: #2f3036;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
    background: #19c589;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #2f3036;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
    background: #19c589;
    color: #fff;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
    display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
    display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 250px){
    /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
    ul {
        position: static;
        display: none;
    }
    /*Create vertical spacing*/
    li {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    /*Make all menu links full width*/
    ul li, li a {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: If you are linking to a JSfiddle please do not put the URL in formatting as if it were meant to be a code block. The inline code ticks are also unnecessary.

Comment: my apology, still trying to get the hang of stackoverflow. How's this?

Comment: That's a lot better, thank you. I hope my answer below is helpful or gets you closer to the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make `li ul` positions, absolute so they wont take room.

```css
#wrap-nav {
  display: block;
  margin:2rem;
  z-index: 900;
  padding: 5rem;
}
#main-nav {
  display: block;
  z-index: 950;
  padding: 1rem;
  float: right;
}
/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:.1rem;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
  z-index: 980;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
    /*this is the trick*/
    position:absolute;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 250px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<ul id="main-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About ￬</a>
                        <ul class="hidden">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Who We Are</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">What We Do</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Portfolio ￬</a>
                        <ul class="hidden">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Photography</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Illustration</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the result of one of your listed items:

`<li><a href="#">Web & User Interface Design</a></li>`

Try cutting it down to just User Interface Design and it will not extend as much, if you prevent the nav bar from extending then the text will be cut off, is that your intent? Your desired outcome is a little unclear. And, thank you for making improvements to your question

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldnt appreciate more. I did cut down the 'User Interface design' but my worry is if I need to create a sub-menu with longer text in the future. This may extend again. Is there a way for the Portfolio to stop expanding? Basically keep the width of all menus the same size.